# Letter keys are not working on Windows 8 sometimes?

Tags: windows, windows-8, keyboard

I'm using a Razer Blackwidow and a wireless Logitech keyboard, I've install both Synapse 2.0 and Logitech Setpoint on my computer. The problem begin when I installed Kaspersky 1 week back, sometimes the letter keys are not able to type, even the laptop keyboard is also has the same problem. I mean only letters key are not working, Backspace, Return keys are working well. The problem disappear after 3-5 minutes and happen once in 2 days and appear even I shutdown the Kaspersky protection. This thing is really annoying me. Any solution?

I'm using Windows 8 on a Sony Vaio laptop.

Comment: Uninstall Kaspersky and re-enable Windows Defender (to tide you over a few days of testing). If the problem fails to show up, probably a bug in the AV that you should report on its forum.

Comment: I just experienced a similar issue with only the 'H' key at the unlock screen (tested 2 keyboards); restarting solved. I uninstalled prepackaged McAfee weeks ago and am using Windows Defender.

Comment: I experienced this problem with "o" using the dvorak layout (the "s" key for the rest of you) on the unlock screen in Windows 8.  Turning on the on-screen keyboard would allow it to work again.  Apart from that it worked fine.